# How to use MainActivity's SQLiteDatabase instance in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have a "SQLiteDatabase db" in my `MainActivity`. I initialize it and then call an `AsyncTask` `updateDatabaseTask` in `onCreate()` method as follows:

```
db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
...
updateDatabaseTask  = new UpdateDatabaseTask();
updateDatabaseTask.execute();
```

I use "db" in `updateDatabaseTask`'s `doInBackground()` method as follows:

```
Cursor c = db.query(...);
```

However I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase
```

Shouldn't we initialize a database instance at the beginning and be able to use it in different tasks, functions, etc?

Comment: Do NOT close db unless the activity is destroyed. If you never close db object even in Activity.onDestroy(), it is OK because db is just a handle. If your app closes errorlessly, then db will be automatically closed by the OS.

Comment: Can you post full code of doInBackground

Comment: I removed `databaseHelper.close()` from `onPause()` of `MainActivity` and the problem seems to be solved :) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Neaetmul points in the comment above, I removed `databaseHelper.close()` from `onPause()` of `MainActivity` and the problem solved. However, I haven't figured why this line causes such a runtime error, because app is running while I am using it...